# Identifying unique socket connection in play WebSockets

Tags: scala, playframework, websocket

Am new to  play framework and Scala. I am implementing web sockets in play 2.5.3 and Scala using iteratees and Enumerators. I want to know if there is a way to identify the unique webSocket connection  from all the Channels connected. Suppose i want to send a msg to one particular user from all the active connections. how am i able to do that?

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is to have somewhere in your application a `Map[User, Websocket]` to associate a user with his websocket connection. You have one example [here](http://www.lightbend.com/activator/template/play-akka-angular-websocket)

This works if your application is running on a single node. For multi-node, I recommend you this activator tutorial: [Clustered Chat with Play Framework](http://www.lightbend.com/activator/template/clustered-chat)

Comment: Sorry, but how to get that webSocket instance if am using `def func_name =  WebSocket.using[string] { request => /* remaining logic */ } '

Comment: I should have said `Channel` instead of Websocket, the `Channel` will allow you to push messages to your client. See this [code example](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.5.x/documentation/manual/working/scalaGuide/main/async/code/ScalaWebSockets.scala#L323)